# Event listener never asserts while testing on Laravel / PHPUnit

Tags: laravel, lumen, laravel-testing, phpunit

I'm trying to send a test email and assert (using events) that it was sent.

The test runs fine and the event in fact happen (I'm logging the event handler method on LogSendingMessage class), but the `expectsEvents` never assert, neither before, neither after the `Mail::send` method.

```
public function testSendSimpleMailOverSMTP()
{
    // Send methods
    $fromMail = 'my@mail.com';
    $fromName = 'Tiago Gouvêa';
    $toMail = 'myanother@mail.com';
    $toName = 'Tiago Gouvêa';
    $subject = 'Mail testing123';

    $view = 'SimpleMail';
    $data = array('body' => "Olá fulano");

    $this->expectsEvents(Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending::class);
    $this->expectsEvents(Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent::class);

    Mail::send($view, $data, function (Illuminate\Mail\Message $message) use ($toMail, $toName, $fromMail, $fromName, $subject) {
        $message->to($toMail, $toName)->subject($subject);
        $message->from($fromMail, $fromName);
    });
}
```

Here on stack has another questions some like, but, none of then worked for me. I appreciate any help. :)

Comment: Have you tried using `Event::assertDispatched(Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending::class);` ?

Comment: @SalvatoreQZeroastro I cannot find the right import for Event class. What's its namespace?

Comment: `Event` is the standard event facade, `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event` - you have to run `Event::fake()` before the test, to swap it with `EventFake` (a support facade for testing - the swap is implicit when running the method)

Comment: @SalvatoreQZeroastro  Ok, I tried like you said but I'm keeping getting "The expected [Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending] event was not dispatched"